# Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty }x^2\cos\left(\mathrm{e}^x\right)~\mathrm{d}x $ convergence proof?

Tags: calculus

Tried a few things, none of them worked. I am really out of ideas at the moment.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\! x^2\cos(\mathrm{e}^x)~\mathrm{d}x $$

How do I prove that this integral converges?

Comment: See [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: Questions regarding homework assignments are more than welcome, provided that they: Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea). Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a change of variables.  Setting $u = e^x$, we have
$$
I = \int_1^\infty \frac{[\ln(u)]^2}{u}\cos(u)\,du
$$
Noting that $\frac{[\ln(u)]^2}{u} \to 0$, you could compare this integral to some (convergent) alternating series.